# Is there a browser agnostic way to increase a checkbox's size without changing HTML markup?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, input

Is there a browser agnostic way to increase a `<input type="checkbox">`'s size without changing HTML markup ?

I tried to change height and width in the CSS but the problems is that in Firefox the checkbox gets pixelated. In Opera only the logic size of the input increases, not the visual.

Should I use a `<label> and :before` pseudo selectors to make it look nice and big, what are the alternative solutions?

Trying to avoid JavaScript if possible.

Comment: Note that asking for "alternative solutions" is pretty broad; there are literally hundreds of them. Serg has presented one of them, but there are many others...

Comment: OK, started a bounty for more answers

Comment: for the firefox issue: try `-moz-appearance: none;` and then configure the border. the checkmark itself should be rendered via SVG and thus scalable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are right in your assumption, cross-browser support is inconsistent. If you want bulletproof customization you will want to write your own solution.

Personally, I would look at solutions used by major `css` frameworks such as [Bootstrap](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/animated-radios-amp-checkboxes-nojs) and [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/4.3.2/components/custom-forms.html).

From one of the links:

```css
label input[type="checkbox"]{ display: none; }

label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .cr > .cr-icon{
    transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}

label input[type="checkbox"] + .cr > .cr-icon{
    transform: scale(3) rotateZ(-20deg);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked="">
    <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
    Click Me
</label>
```

```css
label input[type="checkbox"]{ display: none; }

label input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .cr > .cr-icon{
    transform: scale(1) rotateZ(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
}

label input[type="checkbox"] + .cr > .cr-icon{
    transform: scale(3) rotateZ(-20deg);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all .3s ease-in;
}

.cr-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
    font-size: inherit;
    text-rendering: auto;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.cr-icon:before {
    content: "\2713";  
}
```

```html
<label>
    <input type="checkbox" value="" checked="">
    <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon"></i></span>
    Click Me
</label>
```

Comment: could you give a more concrete answer ?

Comment: Updated with an example.

Comment: By the way, the CSS you are using loads a custom font (FontAwesome) -- the bounty was saying it should not be required. I guess you may remove it and use a browser font, although it may not look as nice.

Comment: @GyumFox well, OP can let me know if he wants me to tweak the code. This technique obviously doesn't rely on the font. It can be just a square that changes color on toggle.

Comment: I have added another snippet, this one uses an unicode character and doesn't need font-awesome

Answer (score 2):

For this you can use pseudo selector

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test1" />
<label for="test1">Checkbox</label>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Base for label styling */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked {
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
}
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* checkbox aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left:0; top: -1px;
  width: 17px; height: 17px;
  border: 1px solid #bbb;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
/* checked mark aspect */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after,
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  content: '✔';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px; left: 4px;
  font-size: 19px;
  line-height: 0.8;
  color: #09ad7e;
  transition: all .2s;
}
/* checked mark aspect changes */
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked) + label:after {
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(0);
}
[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:after {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
}
/* disabled checkbox */
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:not(:checked) + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:before {
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: #bbb;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled:checked + label:after {
  color: #999;
}
[type="checkbox"]:disabled + label {
  color: #aaa;
}
/* accessibility */
[type="checkbox"]:checked:focus + label:before,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked):focus + label:before {
  border: 1px dotted blue;
}

/* hover style just for information */
label:hover:before {
  border: 1px solid #4778d9!important;
}
```

for updated fiddle [click here](https://jsfiddle.net/c2ofjjdv/)

Comment: Why do you use [type="checkbox"]:not(:checked),
[type="checkbox"]:checked selector instead of just [type="checkbox"] ?

Comment: @WalleCyril ! You are right we can use `input[type="checkbox"]:checked`

Comment: I think the selectors you use are over specific

Answer (score 0):

Here is the leanest solution I can think of: use a `label` next to a `checkbox`, and style the `label` using a character placed in a `::before` pseudo-element.

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{ display: none; }
input[type="checkbox"]+label::before
{
   content: '☑ ';
   font-size: 1.5em;
}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before
{
   content: '☐ ';
}
```

```html
<input id="cb" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="cb">Click Me</label>
```

You may change the size of the box by customising the font size, or even change the whole style of the checkbox using your custom font.

UPDATE: If you want to customize the look of the box while staying away from using a custom font, you may want to play with SVG backgrounds. Here is an ugly example, but you get the idea (also feel free to use a border for the outside of the checkbox or include it to the SVG):

```css
input[type="checkbox"]{ display: none; }
input[type="checkbox"]+label::before
{
   content: '☐';
   font-size: 1.5em;

}
input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label::before
{
   background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/Checkbox.svg');
   background-size: contain;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center center;
}
```

```html
<input id="cb" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="cb">Click Me</label>
```